# Why after the for loop the values of the arrays go back to their original value?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to solve the next HackerRank problem:

It is New Year's Day and people are in line for the Wonderland rollercoaster ride. Each person wears a sticker indicating their initial position in the queue from to. Any person can bribe the person directly in front of them to swap positions, but they still wear their original sticker. One person can bribe at most two others.

Determine the minimum number of bribes that took place to get to a given queue order. Print the number of bribes, or, if anyone has bribed more than two people, print Too chaotic.

My try:

```
def minimumBribes(q):
    aux = 0
    r = 0
    b = 0
    goal=[]
    a = []
    goal = [i + 1 for i in range(len(q))] 
    a = [0  for i in range(len(q))] 
    
    #r is to check if a person have changed placed more than two time. 
    
    while((q!=goal) and r == 0): 
     
        for i in range(len(q)-1):
            #print("q: " + str(q))
            #print("a: " + str(a))
            if(q[i]>q[i+1]):
                aux = q[i]
                q[i] = q[i+1]
                q[i+1] = aux
                a[i] = a[i] + 1
                b = b + 1
        if (2 in a):
            r = 2
    if(r==2):
        print("Too chaotic")
    else:
        print(b)
```

Input: [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]

Expected output: Too Chaotic

My output: 4

I don't get why after the for loop the values of the arrays
`q`
and
`a`
go back to their original value. Any suggestion would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Please include sample input and expected output and actual output.

Comment: You should step through your code one line at a time, and watch the values of your variables to make sure they're doing what you expect (even on paper if you're not familiar with debugging). For example, just on paper, I can get from `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` to `2, 1, 5, 3, 4` with only 3 swaps, not 4. I would suggest coming up with a method that identifies the next swap, and only performs 1 swap per iteration until the lists match.

Comment: I know that my code its not correct but I think its because the values of the arrays q and a are returning to their original value after the for. For example, this is what I get when I print a and q: q: [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
a: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q: [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
a: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q: [1, 2, 5, 3, 4]
a: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q: [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
a: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
q: [2, 5, 1, 3, 4]
a: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q: [2, 5, 1, 3, 4]
a: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
q: [2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
a: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
q: [2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
a: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
q: [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
a: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
...